# Confused on Numerical Integration: Making a plot

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I want to make a plot for the following integral:

$$\frac{4B^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\displaystyle\int_{\sqrt{2gz}}^{\infty}dv\frac{v^2 e^{-Bv^2}}{\sqrt{v^2-2gz}}$$

I would like to plot this for different values of v.

And am new to Mathematica and thus very confused on how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post the Mathematica code instead of LaTeX formula.

Comment: Hi @890JHS, welcome to Mma.SE!  start by taking the [tour] now, so you understand how the site works. It helps us to help you when you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) that contains a minimum working example of your problem. Pleas [edit] your question to provide code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**, i.e the equation in code (no images, and in addition to $\LaTeX$) and the values of the parameters.

Comment: You cannot do a numeric integration unless you assign numeric values to the parameters `B`, `g`, and `z`. Edit your question to include their values.

Comment: Thanks Bob, I have suitable values for B, g and z that I want to assign but am unable to do so as well.

Comment: @890JHS can you share those values? Please don't make us guess, help us to help you.  Use the comments section only for comments, add new information by [edit]ing the question.

Comment: Yes definitely, sorry for the confusion, g= 9.8 B=1, z=1 as well

Comment: You cannot plot the integral for different values `v` because `v` is the integration-variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `g z>0,B>0` the integral might be solved analytically

```
Integrate[(v^2 Exp[-B v^2])/Sqrt[v^2 - 2 g z], {v, Sqrt[2 g z], Infinity},Assumptions -> {g z > 0, B > 0}]
(*g Sqrt[\[Pi]] z MeijerG[{{}, {-(1/2)}}, {{-1, 0},{}}, 2 B g z]*)
```

But the result doesn't depend on `v`!

Comment: I see, I was also able to get a similar analytic solution, perhaps I will try plotting this up. What does Meijer refer to here? Thanks again!

Comment: @890JHS For Mathematica documentation go to https://reference.wolfram.com/language/?source=nav and type the name of the function into the search box and tap Enter and then select the function from the list it returns. Then (usually) click on the orange Details or Details and Options to see more detailed information

Comment: Great resource, Bill, thanks!

Comment: Or, while in Mathematica, highlight any unknown symbol (e.g., `MeijerG`} and press `F1` for help. Also, in the case of built-in functions, the interactive tooltip contains a link ("get info" symbol) to the documentation page.